# Filtering an NSArray with custom objects

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have a class like this :

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject 
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *type;
@end
```

and I am creating an array like this:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
MyObject *obj = [[MyObject alloc] init];
obj.type = @"test1";
[array addObject:obj];

MyObject *obj2 = [[MyObject alloc] init];
obj2.type = @"test2";
[array addObject:obj2];

MyObject *obj3 = [[MyObject alloc] init];
obj3.type = @"test1";
[array addObject:obj3];
```

I would like to filter the array to just have only the objects which have different types, in my example just to have obj1, obj2 and remove the obj3.

Comment: If you don't mind efficiency, just use a nested loop to remove objects appearing a second time, and then sort (sorting has little to do with removing objects having the same types however).

Comment: Sorry for the closing vote. I've read your question quicly. Cheers.

Comment: If any moderator can remove the closing vote, this would help. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something along these lines should do the trick:

```
NSMutableSet * types = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:10];
NSPredicate * filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {

    if ([types containsObject:[evaluatedObject type]]) {
        return NO;
    }
    else {
        [types addObject:[evaluatedObject type]];
        return YES
    }
}];
NSArray * filteredArray = [detailedError filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filterPredicate];
```

The above code keeps the first object of each type and removes others.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this by just overriding *hash* and *isEqual*:

```
- (BOOL) isEqual:(id)object
{
    if([object isKindOfClass: [self class]])
        return [_type isEqualToString: object];
    return NO;
}

- (NSInteger) hash
{
    return [_type hash];
}
```

Then taking the distinct objects array from a set created from the array:

```
NSArray* filteredArray= [NSSet setWithArray: array].allObjects;
```

Comment: Even though this is very elegant solution for this problem, I think it might have side effects if the OP needs to use isEqual: somewhere else, maybe obj1.type == obj2.type does not always necessitate obj1==obj2

Comment: This is intended to be used on a class like OP's *MyObject*, which has only *type* and no other properties.